# TableView and the home indicator on iPhone X

Tags: ios, uitableview, iphone-x

I am using both `UITableViewController` and `UITableView` in one project.

An `UITableView` in an `UITableViewController` overlays the home indicator on iPhone X.
But an `UITableView` in an `UIViewController` doesn't overlay the home indicator on iPhone X.
Should I fit one?
And which one is correct when I consider about safe area?

e.x.

[image: UITableViewController]

[image: UITableView on UIViewController]

Answer (score 4):

You can continue to use a `UITableView` on a standard `UIViewController`. Just set auto layout so the bottom of the tableview is flush with the bottom of the superview (and not the margin). Then set the `insetsContentViewsToSafeArea` property of the tableview to `true`

**Swift:**

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = true;
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [tableView setInsetsContentViewsToSafeArea:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you have set `UIScrollView.appearance().contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never` in appDelegate, remember to set the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` property of tableView to `.automatic`/`.always`/`.scrollableAxes`, otherwise, the content at the bottom would be obstructed. In iOS 11.1 and earlier versions, we set it to `.never` to prevent an insets-adjusting animation on popping, but now(iOS 11.2) I try not setting it at the beginning, and the app works correctly. So, I think the unexpected animation in the previous version might be a bug or the handling procedures have changed.

Answer (score 2):

This is because table view in UITableViewController is root view. It will extend to full screen. But you can make constraints to bottom layout guide for table view in UIViewController. So you can use UIViewController. Or you can set content insets in UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me, in **iOS 12**:

I tried setting `insetsContentViewsToSafeArea` but that didn't work, although it set me on the right path. What fixed it for me was setting the "Content Insets" in the nib/storyboard to "Never" (in the code, that property is `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`).

Explanation: It seems that, for iPhoneX and above, the system automatically adds some bottom padding for table views so that the content goes above the home indicator.